# UI view of each template in Angular

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, web-deployment

I am exploring a codebase of an web application built in Angular(2) using visual studio code. There are a bunch of different components and I would like to have a visual view(UI view) of each template to speed up my understanding of the code. I want to know if there is any tool that can help me achieve this? Thank you!

Comment: does it have to be within VScode?

Comment: Yes. It needs to be within VScode.

Answer (score 1):

You could use,

[www.StackBlitz.com](http://www.StackBlitz.com)

It is not within Visual Studio Code (it is 100% browser based)

But it is powered Visual Studio Code and it has a side-by-side view of the code and the output.